# ActionBarSherlock overlapping fragment in the same tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, overlapping

I have a problema with my app.. I have to change a fragment in a tab, but when i do this the new fragment overlap on the old fragment. This is my code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

ViewPager mViewPager;
TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;
TextView tabCenter;
TextView tabText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    mViewPager = new ViewPager(this);
    mViewPager.setId(R.id.pager);

    setContentView(mViewPager);
    ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mViewPager);

    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Home"),
            FragmentTab1.class, createBundle("ft1"));
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("FujiSan"),
            FragmentTab2.class, null);
}

public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
        ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }

    public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(),
                info.args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
            int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }
}

public static Bundle createBundle( String title ) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString( "title", title );
    return bundle;
}
}
```

I have two tabs and i add to this two fragments. This the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/home"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

 >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

And this is the code of FragmentTab1:

```
public class FragmentTab1 extends SherlockFragment {

static Context context;

@Override
public SherlockFragmentActivity getSherlockActivity() {
    return super.getSherlockActivity();
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RelativeLayout view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragmenttab1, container, false);
    context = getActivity();

    Button guasti = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bGuasti);
    Button segnala = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.segnalaDisservizio);
    guasti.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Fragment newFragment = new FragmentTab2();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame1, newFragment, "new frsg");
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
            getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }
    });
```

With a layout that have a frameLayout:

```
  ...omissis...  
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

</FrameLayout>
```

This the result: in red thera are the components of the second fragment [image]

Answer (score 1):

In all your xml files, should define the background color for it, it will solve the problem :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/home"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/frame1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
```

Add this `android:background="@android:color/black"` in to the View tag you defined.